# How to know if a driver is loaded as a module in my Linux kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu MATE 22.04 on a chromebook with a custom UEFI framework, and one of the keys (fullscreen key) does not work (the key worked in Chrome OS, so not a hardware issue).

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/MrChromebox/firmware/issues/499) with the UEFI dev, and I was asked the following question.

> the Google vivaldi keyboard driver translates the top row keyboard scancodes into media/action events - is that driver compiled as a module in your kernel? is it loaded?

How do I know if the driver is loaded?

Comment: Read `man lsmod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `locate vivaldi | grep kernel` to figure out that the module is called `hid-vivaldi` and `hid-vivaldi-common`.

`sudo modinfo hid-vivaldi` shows that the driver is present, and `lsmod | grep vivaldi` shows that it is in use.